# Find the order of magnitude of the equation solution

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, roots

Find the order of magnitude of the following equation solution:
$$
x(\ln x)^{2001}=n
$$

Comment: The order of magnitude is related to the common logarithm of $x$. Try rewriting to make $\log x$ the subject of the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before computing the order of magnitude of the solution, we can get a solution using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$
\begin{align}
n
&=x\log(x)^{2001}\\
&=\log(x)^{2001}\ e^{\log(x)}\\
n^{1/2001}/2001
&=\log(x)/2001\ e^{\log(x)/2001}\\
\mathrm{W}(n^{1/2001}/2001)
&=\log(x)/2001
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
x=e^{2001\mathrm{W}(n^{1/2001}/2001)}
$$

---

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{\log(x)}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(x)+2001\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}\\
&=1+2001\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, as Antonio Vargas points out, $(1)$ implies that
$$
x=n\log(x)^{-2001}\sim n\log(n)^{-2001}\tag{2}
$$
Thus, in terms of orders of magnitude, $(2)$ is a more precise statement of
$$
x=O\left(n\log(n)^{-2001}\right)\tag{3}
$$

---

Here is a plot of $\log(\log(x))$ vs $\log(\log(n))$:

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

For $\log(\log(n))\le5$ (i.e. $n\le2.85112\times10^{64}$), $\log(\log(x))$ is very close to $0$ (i.e. $x\approx e$).

For $\log(\log(n))\ge12$ (i.e. $n\ge3.2197\times10^{70683}$, $\log(\log(x))$ is very close to $\log(\log(n))$.

Comment: +1.  And now that $\log(x) \sim \log(n)$ is known, we get $$x = n(\log(x))^{-2001} \sim n(\log(n))^{-2001}$$ immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account robjohn's answer, the approximate value is $e$.  I give you a few solutions for $x(n)$. $$x(10^0)=2.71692$$ $$x(10^1)=2.72005$$ $$x(10^2)=2.72319$$ $$x(10^3)=2.72633$$ $$x(10^4)=2.72948$$  $$x(10^5)=2.73263$$  $$x(10^6)=2.73579$$ $$x(10^7)=2.73896$$ $$x(10^8)=2.74214$$ $$x(10^9)=2.74533$$ while $e=2.71828$.

You could check that we obtain a value $x=3$, which is only $10$% larger than $e$, it would be required that $n>1.61\times 10^{82}$ which is quite large.

**Added after robjohn's last answers**

As shown by robjohn, the solution of $$x \log
(x)^k=n$$ is given by $$x=e^{k\mathrm{W}(n^{1/k}/k)}$$ which corresponds to $$\log( x)=k\mathrm{W}(n^{1/k}/k)$$ For large values of its argument, Lambert function can be expanded as $$\mathrm{W}(y) \simeq \log (y)-\log (\log (y))+\frac{\log (\log (y))}{\log (y)}$$ Using $y=\frac{n^{\frac{1}{k}}}{k}$, $\log(y)=\frac{\log (n)}{k}-\log (k)$ and then $$\log(x) \simeq k \left(\frac{\log (n)}{k}-\log (k)-\log \left(\frac{\log (n)}{k}-\log
   (k)\right)+\frac{\log \left(\frac{\log (n)}{k}-\log
   (k)\right)}{\frac{\log (n)}{k}-\log (k)}\right)$$ which shows the respective roles of $n$ and $k$ and the fact that the asymptotic value is  $\log(x) \simeq \log(n)-k \log(k)$

For $k=2001$ and $n=10^{1000000}$, the previous expansion gives $x=2.08528\times 10^{987280}$ for an exact value $x=2.14287\times10^{987280}$ as reported by robjohn.

Comment: If we use larger values for $n$, we get $$x\left(10^{1000000}\right)=2.14287\times10^{987280}$$ getting closer to the ratio of $1$ for the logs given in my answer.

Comment: @robjohn. Yes for sure and I have been very glad to see your inspiring answer ! $x$ is an increasing function of $n$ but really slow. What would have been funny is : what is the limit of $x$ when $n$ goes to infinity. I was trying to give an order of magnitude for human sized values of $n$. By the way, the number of atoms in the whole universe is smaller than $10^{1000000}$. Cheers.

Comment: I have added a plot of $\log(\log(x))$ vs $\log(\log(n))$. There we can see why for $n\le10^{64}$ we have that $x\approx e$.

Comment: Assuming approximately $10^{80}$ atoms in the universe, $x\left(10^{80}\right)\doteq2.991657$. In any case,  mathematics doesn't usually care how many atoms there are in the universe. Since the order of a function depends on how it acts near $\infty$, we have $x=O\left(n\log(n)^{-2001}\right)$.